# Accessing Binned Data with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a set of data for which i have put into a data frame and then binned:

```
print(data1)


[[-1.90658883e+00  5.66881290e-01  1.45443907e+00]
 [-1.82926850e+00  2.53325112e-01  1.45480072e+00]
 [-1.59073925e+00  5.33264011e-01  1.45461954e+00]
 ...
 [ 2.86246982e+02  4.52961148e-01  6.19121328e+00]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data1,)
print(df)
bins  = [0,50,100,150,200,250,300,400]
df1 = pd.cut(df[0],bins, labels = False)
print(df1)


1     0
2     0
 ..
500   4
501   4
502   5
```

0  through 5 are the bin labels. I want to be able to access the data in each bin/category and store it in a variable. Something like this:

```
x = df1(4) # this doesnt work, just an example.
```

^ meaning I want to access the data stored in the 4th bin in the pandas dataframe and assign it to the variable x as an array, but I am unsure how to do that.

Comment: Could you clarify your desired output?  I don't understand what `df1(bin / category 4)` means, and it's not clear how to get the output `[0.1 0.2 ...]` from your inputs.

Comment: @DSM edited my post

Comment: Are you supposed to do this for one column of `df` at a time? Or do you want to access all elements of `df` in that bin? And are you expecting, as result, the elements of `df` in which the first value (0 column) are in the 4th bin?

Comment: @vhcandido  Yes, i would like to do it for 1 data column at a time. and yes, exactly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and pass a boolean array to it.

```
bi = pd.cut(df[0], bins, labels=False)
x = df.loc[bi == 4]
```